# Unable to end session/log out using lightdm (16.04)

Tags: 16.04, gnome, lightdm

My system is refusing to allow me to log out from my gnome session when I click the "Log Out" button. I can log in just fine, and the session appears to work okay. However, when I attempt to log out (or type "gnome-session-quit" at a terminal), I am ultimately brought back to a fresh session.

**UPDATE:** Eventually, the system will let me log out, but I have to log out four times. `lightdm --session-child` appears to be spawned multiple times, but once it has been cleared, I can log out.

**UPDATE 2:** Added some information from the syslog, showing that dbus is rejecting "ReleaseSession" from the `lightdm --session-child` process. I think this has to be some kind of permission thing, but I'm not sure where to look or how to reset it.

I am running 16.04.5 LTS, kernel 4.4.0-130-generic, and I have the nvidia-384 drivers installed.

Some notes:

- Open applications are closed, and the Unity/Gnome display goes away after a confirm that I want to log out. I'm left with a desktop background for a few seconds, then the Unity/Gnome interface pops up again, just like I had started a new session.
- This behavior occurs when I use both Gnome (gnome.desktop) and Ubuntu/Unity (ubuntu.desktop) sessions.
- The behavior does not occur when I use gdm3, only lightdm.
- I have tried cleaning out lightdm, removing the contents of /var/lightdm, and resetting the files in /etc/lightdm. I've uninstalled and reinstalled lightdm as well as tried `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`. No luck.
- The problem occurs for old users as well as newly-created users.
- The behavior is the same using the "nvidia-340" drivers.
- I have also attempted uninstalling and reinstalling xinit and gnome to no avail. Again, the session lets me log in, but I can't seem to log out.
- Unfortunately, I'm not quite sure when the behavior started, so I can't trace it to a particular update or system change. Certainly within the past two months.

I'm not exactly sure where to start with the logs. However, I've included the results from `/var/log/lightdm`.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**UPDATE 2:** Here are the entries from syslog. There a quite a few of these:

```
    dbus: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.121" (uid=1046 pid=3079 comm="lightdm --session-child 12 19 ") interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member="ReleaseSession" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.login1" (uid=0 pid=1148 comm="/lib/systemd/systemd-logind "): 1 Time(s)
    dbus: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.126" (uid=1046 pid=2640 comm="lightdm --session-child 12 19 ") interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member="ReleaseSession" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.login1" (uid=0 pid=1142 comm="/lib/systemd/systemd-logind "): 1 Time(s)
```

**UPDATE:** As mentioned above, lightdm appears to span multiple `lightdm --session-child` processes. I have a similar system that behaves normally. On that system, after login, only one process exists after login, and it is owned by root (for the greeter?). On my system, two `lightdm --session-child` processes exist after login, and are owned by the user. See below for a freshly-created user (fresh):

Session-child processes before login:

```
root      1530  1442  0 11:03 ?        00:00:00 lightdm --session-child 16 19
root      1647  1442  0 11:03 ?        00:00:00 lightdm --session-child 12 19
```

Session-child processes after the first login:

```
root      1647  1442  0 11:03 ?        00:00:00 lightdm --session-child 12 19
fresh     3109  1647  0 11:04 ?        00:00:00 lightdm --session-child 12 19
fresh     3110  3109  0 11:04 ?        00:00:00 lightdm --session-child 12 19
```

Session-child processes after the first logout attempt:

```
root      1647  1442  0 11:03 ?        00:00:00 lightdm --session-child 12 19
fresh     3109  1647  0 11:04 ?        00:00:00 lightdm --session-child 12 19
```

Session-child processes after the second logout attempt:

```
root      1647  1442  0 11:03 ?        00:00:00 lightdm --session-child 12 19
fresh     4470  1647  0 11:06 ?        00:00:00 lightdm --session-child 12 19
```

Session-child processes after the third logout attempt. On a normal system, a single session-child process, owned by root, is the typical result after the user logs in. On my system, I have to log out three times to get down to this point:

```
root      1647  1442  0 11:03 ?        00:00:00 lightdm --session-child 12 19
```

Session-child processes after the fourth logout attempt (a successful logout):

```
root      5723  1442  0 11:08 ?        00:00:00 lightdm --session-child 16 19
root      5775  1442  0 11:08 ?        00:00:00 lightdm --session-child 12 19
```

I have no idea why so many of these processes are being spawned, or why they refuse to die. Worse, I have no idea where to look for what might be causing the hangup. I see nothing obvious in the lightdm logs.

lightdm.log:

```
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting Light Display Manager 1.18.3, UID=0 PID=12609
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-disable-log-backup.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-greeter-wrapper.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-guest-wrapper.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/90-nvidia.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG:   [SeatDefaults] is now called [Seat:*], please update this configuration
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/local/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /etc/xdg/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Using D-Bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xlocal
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xremote
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module unity
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Monitoring logind for seats
[+0.00s] DEBUG: New seat added from logind: seat0
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Loading properties from config section Seat:*
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating greeter session
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating display server of type x
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting local X display on VT 7
[+0.00s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+0.00s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+0.00s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Launching X Server
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Launching process 12616: /usr/bin/X -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
[+0.00s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Waiting for ready signal from X server :0
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Acquired bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Registering seat with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Loading users from org.freedesktop.Accounts
[+0.01s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User3004 added
[+0.01s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User5008 added
[+0.01s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User5015 added
[+0.01s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1045 added
[+0.01s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1004 added
[+0.01s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1019 added
[+0.01s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User5007 added
[+0.01s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1009 added
[+0.01s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User5006 added
[+0.02s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1063 added
[+0.02s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User5013 added
[+0.02s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1023 added
[+0.02s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1032 added
[+0.02s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1064 added
[+0.02s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1108 added
[+0.02s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User5000 added
[+0.02s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1102 added
[+0.02s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User5001 added
[+0.02s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1101 added
[+0.03s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1069 added
[+0.03s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1013 added
[+0.03s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1084 added
[+0.03s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1027 added
[+0.03s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1104 added
[+0.03s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User5010 added
[+0.03s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1030 added
[+0.04s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1016 added
[+0.04s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1025 added
[+0.04s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1099 added
[+0.04s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1047 added
[+0.04s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1058 added
[+0.04s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User5009 added
[+0.04s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1038 added
[+0.04s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1087 added
[+0.04s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1079 added
[+0.04s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User3002 added
[+0.04s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1066 added
[+0.04s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1103 added
[+0.04s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1074 added
[+0.05s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User2000 added
[+0.05s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1096 added
[+0.05s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1075 added
[+0.05s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1098 added
[+0.05s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1052 added
[+0.05s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1035 added
[+0.05s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1053 added
[+0.05s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1097 added
[+0.05s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1044 added
[+0.05s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1010 added
[+0.05s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User3001 added
[+0.05s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1076 added
[+0.06s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1050 added
[+0.06s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User3005 added
[+0.06s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1081 added
[+0.06s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1061 added
[+0.06s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1036 added
[+0.06s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1089 added
[+0.06s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1011 added
[+0.06s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1086 added
[+0.06s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1083 added
[+0.06s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1021 added
[+0.06s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1095 added
[+0.06s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1056 added
[+0.07s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1001 added
[+0.07s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1073 added
[+0.07s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1031 added
[+0.07s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User5004 added
[+0.07s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1015 added
[+0.07s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1065 added
[+0.07s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User5003 added
[+0.07s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1042 added
[+0.07s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1088 added
[+0.07s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1067 added
[+0.07s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1059 added
[+0.07s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1092 added
[+0.08s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1039 added
[+0.08s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1024 added
[+0.08s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User5011 added
[+0.08s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1051 added
[+0.08s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1012 added
[+0.08s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User5002 added
[+0.08s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1093 added
[+0.08s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1043 added
[+0.08s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1070 added
[+0.08s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1040 added
[+0.08s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1014 added
[+0.08s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1062 added
[+0.08s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1100 added
[+0.09s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1078 added
[+0.09s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1007 added
[+0.09s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1090 added
[+0.09s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1000 added
[+0.09s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1080 added
[+0.09s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1094 added
[+0.09s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1091 added
[+0.09s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1060 added
[+0.09s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User3003 added
[+0.09s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1105 added
[+0.09s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1057 added
[+0.10s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1006 added
[+0.10s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1071 added
[+0.10s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User3000 added
[+0.10s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1005 added
[+0.10s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1106 added
[+0.10s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1034 added
[+0.10s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1008 added
[+0.10s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1022 added
[+0.10s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1072 added
[+0.10s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1018 added
[+0.10s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User5012 added
[+0.10s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1046 added
[+0.11s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1055 added
[+0.11s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User5014 added
[+0.11s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1041 added
[+0.11s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1028 added
[+0.11s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1077 added
[+0.11s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1082 added
[+0.11s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1003 added
[+0.11s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1048 added
[+0.11s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1029 added
[+0.11s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1033 added
[+0.11s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1054 added
[+0.11s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1020 added
[+0.11s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1037 added
[+0.12s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1049 added
[+0.12s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User5005 added
[+0.12s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1107 added
[+0.12s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1068 added
[+0.12s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1002 added
[+0.12s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1085 added
[+0.12s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1026 added
[+0.12s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1017 added
[+0.12s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to 
[+0.12s] CRITICAL: session_get_login1_session_id: assertion 'session != NULL' failed
[+0.67s] DEBUG: Got signal 10 from process 12616
[+0.67s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Got signal from X server :0
[+0.67s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Connecting to XServer :0
[+0.67s] DEBUG: Launching process 12631: /sbin/prime-offload
[+0.68s] DEBUG: Process 12631 exited with return value 0
[+0.68s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Exit status of /sbin/prime-offload: 0
[+0.68s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server ready, starting session authentication
[+0.68s] DEBUG: Session pid=12637: Started with service 'lightdm-greeter', username 'lightdm'
[+0.84s] DEBUG: Session pid=12637: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+0.84s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session authenticated, running command
[+0.84s] DEBUG: Session pid=12637: Running command /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-greeter-session /usr/sbin/unity-greeter
[+0.84s] DEBUG: Creating shared data directory /var/lib/lightdm-data/lightdm
[+0.84s] DEBUG: Session pid=12637: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/seat0-greeter.log
[+0.90s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+0.90s] DEBUG: Activating login1 session c4
[+0.90s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to c4
[+0.90s] DEBUG: Session c4 is already active
[+1.02s] DEBUG: Greeter connected version=1.18.3 resettable=false
[+1.07s] DEBUG: Greeter start authentication
[+1.07s] DEBUG: Session pid=12698: Started with service 'lightdm', username '(null)'
[+1.07s] DEBUG: Session pid=12698: Got 1 message(s) from PAM
[+1.07s] DEBUG: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
[+10.84s] DEBUG: Continue authentication
[+10.84s] DEBUG: Session pid=12698: Got 1 message(s) from PAM
[+10.84s] DEBUG: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
[+12.90s] DEBUG: Continue authentication
[+13.31s] DEBUG: Session pid=12698: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+13.31s] DEBUG: Authenticate result for user fresh: Success
[+13.31s] DEBUG: User fresh authorized
[+13.31s] DEBUG: Greeter requests default session
[+13.31s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping greeter; display server will be re-used for user session
[+13.31s] DEBUG: Session pid=12637: Sending SIGTERM
[+13.33s] DEBUG: Greeter closed communication channel
[+13.33s] DEBUG: Session pid=12637: Exited with return value 0
[+13.33s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session stopped
[+13.33s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Greeter stopped, running session
[+13.33s] DEBUG: Registering session with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
[+13.33s] DEBUG: Session pid=12698: Running command /usr/sbin/lightdm-session gnome-session --session=ubuntu
[+13.33s] DEBUG: Creating shared data directory /var/lib/lightdm-data/fresh
[+13.33s] DEBUG: Session pid=12698: Logging to .xsession-errors
```

seat0-greeter.log:

```
** (process:12666): WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
[+0.00s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:502: Starting unity-greeter 16.04.2 UID=118 LANG=en_US.UTF-8
[+0.00s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:505: Setting cursor
Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
[+0.00s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:519: Loading command line options
[+0.00s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:547: Setting GTK+ settings
Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
[+0.04s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:570: Creating Unity Greeter
[+0.04s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:57: Creating background surface
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Connecting to display manager...
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Wrote 22 bytes to daemon
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Read 8 bytes from daemon
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Read 150 bytes from daemon
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Connected version=1.18.3 default-session=ubuntu show-manual-login=false hide-users=true has-guest-account=false show-remote-login=true
[+0.06s] DEBUG: menubar.vala:335: LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LANGUAGE=(null)
[+0.06s] DEBUG: menubar.vala:367: LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LANGUAGE=(null)
[+0.08s] DEBUG: Loaded session /usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop (Ubuntu, This session logs you into Ubuntu)
[+0.08s] DEBUG: Loaded session /usr/share/xsessions/gnome-classic.desktop (GNOME Classic, This session logs you into GNOME Classic)
[+0.08s] DEBUG: Loaded session /usr/share/xsessions/gnome.desktop (GNOME, This session logs you into GNOME)
[+0.08s] DEBUG: Starting authentication for user (null)...
[+0.08s] DEBUG: Wrote 16 bytes to daemon
[+0.11s] DEBUG: main-window.vala:185: Screen is 3840x1200 pixels
[+0.11s] DEBUG: main-window.vala:193: Monitor 0 is 1920x1200 pixels at 0,0
[+0.11s] DEBUG: main-window.vala:193: Monitor 1 is 1920x1200 pixels at 1920,0
[+0.11s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:573: Showing greeter
[+0.11s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:257: Showing main window
[+0.11s] DEBUG: background.vala:483: Regenerating backgrounds
[+0.11s] DEBUG: background.vala:68: Making background /usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png at 1920x1200
[+0.12s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:616: Starting main loop
[+0.12s] DEBUG: Read 8 bytes from daemon
[+0.12s] DEBUG: Read 26 bytes from daemon
[+0.12s] DEBUG: Prompt user with 1 message(s)
[+0.13s] DEBUG: settings-daemon.vala:75: Acquired org.gnome.SessionManager
[+0.13s] DEBUG: settings-daemon.vala:102: Acquired org.gnome.ScreenSaver
[+0.13s] DEBUG: settings-daemon.vala:159: All bus names acquired, starting unity-settings-daemon
[+0.16s] DEBUG: menubar.vala:537: Adding indicator object 0x18df5b0 at position 0
[+0.16s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:240: starting system-ready sound

(nm-applet:12704): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkWidget'

(nm-applet:12704): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_show: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
[+2.87s] DEBUG: Connected to Application Indicator Service.
[+2.88s] DEBUG: menubar.vala:537: Adding indicator object 0x18df450 at position 0
[+2.88s] DEBUG: menubar.vala:537: Adding indicator object 0x18df710 at position 2
[+2.88s] DEBUG: menubar.vala:537: Adding indicator object 0x18df2f0 at position 3
[+2.89s] DEBUG: menubar.vala:537: Adding indicator object 0x18df870 at position 2
[+2.89s] DEBUG: Request current apps
[+2.96s] DEBUG: Building new application entry: :1.14  with icon: nm-device-wired at position 0
[+2.96s] DEBUG: menubar.vala:537: Adding indicator object 0x19dc5f0 at position 5
[+2.96s] DEBUG: background.vala:121: Render of background /usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png complete

** (unity-settings-daemon:12723): WARNING **: Unable to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such method 'RegisterClient'
[+9.85s] DEBUG: Providing response to display manager
[+9.86s] DEBUG: Wrote 21 bytes to daemon
[+9.86s] DEBUG: Read 8 bytes from daemon
[+9.86s] DEBUG: Read 35 bytes from daemon
[+9.86s] DEBUG: Prompt user with 1 message(s)
[+11.91s] DEBUG: Providing response to display manager
[+11.91s] DEBUG: Wrote 24 bytes to daemon
[+12.33s] DEBUG: Read 8 bytes from daemon
[+12.33s] DEBUG: Read 17 bytes from daemon
[+12.33s] DEBUG: Authentication complete for user fresh with return code 0
[+12.33s] DEBUG: Starting default session
[+12.33s] DEBUG: Wrote 12 bytes to daemon
[+12.33s] DEBUG: Read 8 bytes from daemon
[+12.33s] DEBUG: Read 4 bytes from daemon

** (unity-settings-daemon:12723): WARNING **: Name taken or bus went away - shutting down
[+12.33s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:611: Got a SIGTERM
[+12.33s] DEBUG: settings-daemon.vala:78: Failed to acquire name org.gnome.SessionManager
[+12.33s] DEBUG: settings-daemon.vala:105: Failed to acquire name org.gnome.ScreenSaver
upstart: indicator-messages main process ended, respawning
upstart: indicator-bluetooth main process (12707) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-bluetooth main process ended, respawning
upstart: indicator-datetime main process (12709) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-datetime main process ended, respawning
[+12.33s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:135: Failed to acquire name com.canonical.Unity
upstart: indicator-sound main process ended, respawning
[+12.33s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:619: Cleaning up
upstart: indicator-session main process (12712) killed by TERM signal
[+12.33s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:627: Upstart exited with return value 0
upstart: indicator-session main process ended, respawning
[+12.33s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:639: AT-SPI exited with return value 0
[+12.33s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:645: Exiting
upstart: indicator-application main process (12726) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-application main process ended, respawning

(unity-settings-daemon:12723): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed

(unity-settings-daemon:12723): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(unity-settings-daemon:12723): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_handlers_disconnect_matched: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

** (unity-settings-daemon:12723): WARNING **: Lost or failed to acquire name org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor

upstart: indicator-power main process (12708) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-bluetooth main process (13189) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-datetime main process (13190) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-sound main process (13191) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-messages main process (13188) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-session main process (13192) killed by TERM signal
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on my laptop while my desktop PC ran fine with the same setup. The hint which gave me the solution was the difference in

```
systemctl status lightdm
```

When I uninstalled pam-kwallet on the non-working laptop

```
apt remove libpam-kwallet-common libpam-kwallet4 libpam-kwallet5
```

the logoff-problem was gone

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem: I could not logout from the session I started. I too had two lightdm --session-child processes at login. I did not however do the extended fault search like NickF did. I just took the easy way out and changed the display manager. I chose sddm and now everything is back to normal.

I run 16.04 on a old Dell E6230 (i7-3540M CPU @ 3.00GHz and Intel HD Graphics 4000). I use openbox instead of Unity/Gnome which combined with the fact that I changed DM probably means that it is a lightdm problem.

Comment: That's been my solution so far - switched to gdm3 with no problems. Open source software is great when it works, but given the amount of time I spent on this I could have purchased Windows several times over. Glad I'm not crazy!